# android - inserting to a google spreadsheet faster

Tags: android, google-api, google-sheets, cell, google-sheets-api

I have an android app which writes to a google spreadsheet using the sheets API.

I am writing to a specific column, for example - 4

**here is the code of the writing:**

```
URL practiceToUpdateFeedUrl = null;
CellFeed practiceToUpdateCellFeed = null;
int ROWS_NUMBER = 20;

practiceToUpdateFeedUrl = new URI(worksheet.getCellFeedUrl()
.toString() + "?min-col=4&max-col=4").toURL();
practiceToUpdateCellFeed = service.getFeed(practiceToUpdateFeedUrl,
cellFeed.class);

// inserting to the column the text
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS_NUMBER ; i++) {
    newEntry = new CellEntry(i + 1, 4, "insert to cell number" + (i+1));
    service.insert(practiceToUpdateFeedUrl, newEntry);
}
```

**My question is** - is there a faster way to do this?

In this way I make about 20 calls to the API, is there a faster way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully entered data into a google spreadsheet from a hybrid (Phonegap-based) Android and iOS app by just doing an AJAX POST. Check out [this blog post](http://predsdev.blogspot.in/2012/06/embedding-google-drive-form-in-your.html), might be what you are looking for.